# Visual Studio keeps saying "error CS1002: ; expected"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am new to coding with C# in unity and am trying to animate an object in unity, but its saying that I need a semicolon but I can't find where I need one. This is my code:

```
{
  public GameObject arm;
  public float time = 0f;
  public bool timedone = false;
  void Update()
  {
     if(time == 1f)
     {
         timedone = true;
     }
     if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
     {
         arm.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("New Animation");
     }
     else
     {
         if(!timedone)
         {
             time += Time.deltaTime;
         }
         if (timedone)
         {
            arm.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("New State");
            Timereset()
         }  
      }
  }
  void Timereset()
  {
    time == 0f; 
  }
}
```

If you can help me I would be very grateful.

Comment: give us a hint as to what line gets the message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In else condition ,

`Timereset()` doesn't have `;` there should be `Timereset();`

Comment: [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be struggling to navigate to an error. I recommend coding in Visual Studio and I think you are doing that already, because you mention "CS1002" which is a VS error. I'll show you how Visual Studio helps the developer navigate to errors.

In Visual Studio the line number is included in the compiler error message  in the "Error List" tab or window of the GUI. A double-clicking on the error message puts my cursor exactly where the error is (line and column).

Additionally, the error is marked with a red squiggly line in the editor window, exactly where the semicolon is expected.

Here is an image indicating the locations of these features. (Of course there are many more irrelevant compiler errors in this example because I simply copied your code without the Unity development environment.) [image]

Comment: _" I recommend coding in Visual Studio and I think you are doing that already, because you mention "CS1002" which is a VS error"_ - isn't it a C# error?  Anyway, OP already tagged his question with `visual-studio` ;)

Comment: @MickyD Oh my, how could I miss that!? ;-). Anyway, yes, it's C# but the error number is certainly a Visual Studio (or rather, dot net c# compiler) specific number.

Comment: If OP is already using VisualStudio anyway they would simply need to DoubleClick on the error message in the Unity console -> would bring them directly to the according code line

Answer (score 0):

The Update method is called every time a new frame is rendered. In the if condition judgment of the Update method, the `Timereset()` method has no semicolon, and should be written as `Timereset();`.

Comment: Good, though possibly doesn't really add anything new to the existing answers written sometime before.